# DTExec not finding file

Tags: sql, excel, ssms, bids, dtexec

I have a package created, which is loaded onto our SQL server. The package goes into a folder, reads and excel, dumps the excel into a table and then archives it.

When running the package normally (through `BIDS`) it works perfectly fine.

But when I run it through `SSMS`  using the following line:

```
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SQL Server"\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /DTS "<package location>" /SERVER "<Server>" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING V'
```

The section that pulls the Excel name (for each loop in package) reports that it does not find anything.

```
   Description: The For Each File enumerator is empty. The For Each File enumerator did not find any files that matched the file pattern, or the specified directory was empty.
```

The package needs to be run in 32-bit mode to read the excel, which is why I am using the 32-bit `dtexec` location.

Anyone know what's up?

Comment: Maybe different environment variables

Comment: I would not depend on xp_cmdshell for many reasons.  [Create job](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1180/sql-server-integration-services-package-scheduling-with-sql-agent/) and start with TSQL `EXEC dbo.sp_start_job 'job_name'`

Comment: This SQL is not run through a job in SSMS, its an automated process (using automate) which just runs the SQL that I have above when the file is dropped into the location.

Comment: Or are you saying to create a job, and have the SQL just run the job, instead of the dtexec?

Comment: I mean only to exchange xp_cmdshell for job start. Just for testing. Maybe the account that is used with xp_cmdshell does not have permission to get data in directory

Comment: Running it through the job as you suggested is now giving me the error `DTExec: Signature verification failed. The signature status is not present.`

Comment: It is working fine now through the job. I deleted the step and re-made it and it is working both when I run the `EXEC dbo.sp_start_job` manually, and through automate. I'd say it was a `dtexec` permissions issue as you said. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion you should use **[`create SSIS Type Job`](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1180/sql-server-integration-services-package-scheduling-with-sql-agent/)** and change:

```
exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'C:\"Program Files (x86)"\"Microsoft SQL Server"\100\DTS\Binn\DTExec.exe /DTS "<package location>" /SERVER "<Server>" /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING V'
```

with:

```
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job 'job_name';
```

I would also check the account you use when you execute cmd shell. I suspect non sufficient privileges to read specific directory or different environment variable.